# Blank comment on suggested edit UI

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

A bit nitpicking, but if there is [no comment msg](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/69663), I think UI shouldn't show the comment.

[image]

and may be also at /tools/suggested-edits too.

[image]

Comment: Wait... I didn't think you were allowed to suggest an edit without being forced to provide a summary? Something more peculiar could be happening here.

Comment: <!-- Whatever could that be? -->

Comment: ­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­